# System.TypeInitializationException: error thrown when i try to push into git

Tags: git-for-windows

Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Alm.Cli.Program' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
at Microsoft.Alm.Cli.Program..cctor()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.Alm.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
error: unable to read askpass response from 'C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-gui--askpass'
why is this error being thrown

Comment: This looks like an incorrect Git installation. Which version of Git did you install?

Comment: git version 2.32.0.windows.2